# Codeigniter validation errors

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I have a site develop in codeigniter.
I want to validate a form and display some message.
With my code I don't see any error if my input "name_it" is blank. Why?
This is my controller:

```
public function nation_create()
    {
        if($_POST)
        {
            //salvo i dati
            $this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="error">Errore: ', '</p>');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('name_it', 'name_it', 'required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE){
                $this->Nation_model->createNation();
                redirect('backend/nation/nation_list/');
            }
            else{
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
                $this->load->view('backend/include/header_view_logged');
                $this->load->view('backend/nation_create_view',$data);  
                $this->load->view('backend/include/footer_view');
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->load->view('backend/include/header_view_logged');
            $this->load->view('backend/nation_create_view');    
            $this->load->view('backend/include/footer_view');
        }
    }
```

And this is my view (I have  cut more code to read well)

```
<form action='' method='POST'>
   <?php echo validation_errors(); 
   if (isset($errors))
      echo $errors;
   ?>
   <?php echo form_error('name_it'); ?>
   <input type="text" name="name_it" />
   <span id="errorsDiv_name_it"></span>
</form>
```

Comment: have you auto loaded form_helper?

Comment: Yes I have load form_helper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the class `error` with  attribute `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

change:

```
if ($_POST)
```

for:

```
if ($this-input->post())
```

Info: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/input.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `form_validation()->run()` to complete this kind of task. It checks if a POST have been sent and if `validation_rules` returns true.

```
if($this->form_validation()->run() == false)
{
  //load the view
  // other stuff you do while POST is not yet sent or if Input from the user returns false

}else{
  // post has been sent and validiation is TRUE
  // Input is good. . do something
}
```

Comment: Is the same control! Is the same thing that I have already done, you have only change !== FALSE isn't that the problem

Comment: what i am telling you is the `if($_POST)` and `$this->form_validation()->run()` is the same you are having redundant code